# Detect Mod key pressed alone (key pressed and then released)

Tags: x11, key-bindings, awesome-wm

I want to launch a menu when pressing the Mod key alone, but still want to be able to assign shortcuts to Mod + other keys.  In other words, I want to configure the Mod key similar to how it works in Windows 10, where Mod4 alone opens the Start menu and, say, Mod4+R runs a command.

Can this be done with Awesome?

Answer (score 0):

First: Mod4 is not a key, it is a modifier (the fourth one). The keys which activate these modifiers can be figured out by running `/usr/bin/xev`. It shows that keys `Super_L` (left of spacebar) and `Super_R` (right of spacebar) are pressed.

No idea what happens when you assign a key binding to this.

Comment: Good idea.  But if I assign Super_L to run a program and Mod4+X to run another program, then when pressing Mod4+X, both programs are launched.  I want both keybindings to be recognized separately.